# Angular ng serve working fine on localhost but code built using ng build runs slow

Tags: angular, rxjs

We have an Angular app that runs fine when running on localhost. We use the following command -

```
ng serve  --disable-host-check --port 8000 --deploy-url /console/ --base-href /console/
```

Even on adding the `--prod` flag it works fine.

But when the same app is built using

```
ng build --prod  --deploy-url /console/
```

and deployed to a prod server, we are observing some delay while the user is typing something. This is a memory leak issue, probably because we are incorrectly using RxJs/subscription at some place. But the thing I am confused with is why are we not seeing this same issue on localhost. Because of this, it is taking a long time to debug the issue. Every time I need to build the code and deploy to a server to test the performance.

**angular.json**

```
{
  "projects": {
    "ClappiaUI": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "sass"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ClappiaUI",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              
            ],
            "styles": [
              "..."
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "..."
            ],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
              
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ClappiaUI:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ClappiaUI:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ClappiaUI:build"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
        "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
        "skipLibCheck": true
    }
}
```

Comment: would you include the angular.json file content. It will provide important information about the build.

Comment: If you have memory leaks, you should see them also with `ng serve`.

Comment: Updated question with angular.json

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using? The `es5BrowserSupport` property is deprecated, and may be linked to your problem, especially if you are using components built in versions after Angular 8. Do you have differential loading set up?

Comment: We are using Angular 8. Don't have differential loading setup. I've updated the question with my tsconfig.json as well, if it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Use the command like this:

```
ng build --source-map=false
```

Source map is intended only for debugging. Hope it would help!

Comment: `--prod` uses the `production` configuration which already specifies `"sourceMap": false`